# How to adjust screen resolution so image is crisp but larger on an external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

I use an M1 MacBook Air connected to a Lenovo external display. The display is 24". Currently, everything is super tiny on the external display. If I change its resolution, things will get larger but they don't look as crisp.

On some monitors, when changing the resolution, I get something like a slider that gives me options to get either more content on the screen on more space. But on this external monitor I don't get that. When I get to the resolution configurations, I see the following for the external monitor:

[image]

I would like to get this slider:

[image]

Is there an easy way out? What am I missing here?

Comment: It really is the same thing. Just try the offered resolutions.  But you probably won't be happy using a low resolution display with any recent Mac.

Comment: No it's not. In some displays I get the slider and I can make things way without anything else becoming blurry.

Comment: But not with a low res screen.  Anything except 2560x1440 will look very blurry. You need a higher res screen (4K at least) to get varying res and not blurry.

Comment: At a guess (based my 27" 2560x1440 Dell), 2045x1152 might look best. Otherwise 1080p (if that is offered to you).